# Sending POST parameters using HTTPS

Tags: c++

config.h file

```
#define HOST_NAME "test.com"
#define HOST_PORT 5000
```

```
cpr::Response r = cpr::Post(cpr::Url{std::string("https://" + HOST_NAME + ":" + std::to_string(HOST_PORT) + "/setup")}, cpr::Parameters{{"c", computername}, {"u", username}, {"p", hashedPassword}});
```

Errors:

expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

'+' cannot add two pointers

Comment: There is a typo in `https::/`, fix it to `https://`. It is not the fix for your actual problem, but might be confusing later.

Comment: I'm fixing, thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
"https://" + HOST_NAME + ":"
```

This part is expanded to

```
"https://" + "test.com" + ":"
```

You cannot add two string literals directly.

You can concatenate string literals by simply writing them without adding operators like this:

```
"https://" HOST_NAME ":"
```

Another way is using `std::string` to one of what is added:

```
"https://" + std::string(HOST_NAME) + ":"
```

Comment: and the reason why you can't add 2 string literals is because `"..."` declares a `char*`, and you can't add 2 char pointers using +.

Comment: @SuperStormer they aren't pointers. They are arrays. Arrays cannot be added to other arrays. They do decay to pointer but indeed, the decayed pointers cannot be added either.